# Unable to delete sheet from excel and it even gives no error using VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, vba

I have:

```
Public Class ExcelProcess
    Private App As New Excel.Application
    Private Books As Excel.Workbooks = App.Workbooks
    Private WB As Excel.Workbook

Public Sub deleteSheets()
    Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet = getSheetToDelete()
    sheet.Activate()
    sheet.Delete()
    WB.Save()
    WB.Close()
End Sub

Private Function getSheetToDelete() As Excel.Worksheet
     Try
        WB = Books.Open("file.xlsx")
    Catch ex As Exception
        InputOutput.print(ex.Message)
        End
    End Try
    Return WB.Sheets(1)
End Function

End Class
```

I ran the above code, and **it ran successfully with absolutely no errors or exceptions!**

**But the sheet didn't get deleted!**

***< UPDATE >***

I have also tried:

```
sheet.Select()
sheet.Delete()

' Now, this gave me an exception:
Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet.Select(Object Replace)
at DealerCapReport.ExcelProcess.deleteSheets()
at DealerCapReport.MainModule.Main()
```

***< Another UPDATE >***

I tried to check sheet.Delete() boolean for success of failure:

```
If sheet.Delete() Then        ' Error: Expression does not produce a value.
    Console.WriteLine("Can-not Delete")
End If
```

It says **Error: Expression does not produce a value.** in sheet.Delete().

The strange thing is that the [Microsoft API reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb179178%28v=office.12%29.aspx) says that it would produce a Boolean, but it doesn't as it is a Sub and not a function.

How and what is happening?

Am I doing something wrong?

**Please help me fix this!**

Comment: post code for getSheetToDelete()

Comment: I have posted the getSheetToDelete() Function.

Comment: I also tried selecting the sheet before deleting it, and that gave me an exception. Don't know why is that !

Comment: It might help to have some more of the code context from which you are calling the function.  See my answer.

Comment: The `Worksheet.Delete()` method returns a boolean value to say whether it was successful.  Check the result of that.  With all the Excel work you're doing, you'll find the Excel Object Reference useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms262200.aspx

Comment: Your code does not compile (for example, `Private` is invalid for a local variable declaration). Please create a minimal *working* example of the code that does not work, see the "Sample Code" section on http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for details.

Comment: Well thanx for pointing out, actually I copied it from my code to make the function on the fly. Since I wanted to focus on the problem and not the function as I was getting the sheet right -> As I checked in the debugger !

Comment: Now, I have changed the code a lot and still not working !
I have made available the code of the whole class !

Comment: Worksheet.Delete() doesn't produces any value at all.
You can't check that for success  !!

Comment: But the API says that it should produce a boolean, but Visual Studio shows error !

Comment: ".....Visual Studio shows error !" what tha .... so you have an error may be you should have said that first of all you have an error dude fix that first :)

Comment: No.. No.. you are misunderstanding, I mean that sheet.Delete() doesn't return any boolean, so if I will check that in a If statement that will give error.
I have updated the Question, please read that again !!
:)

Comment: You have a mixture of objects - for example `getSheetToDelete` returns a `worksheet` but you are returning `WB` which is a `workbook`. Switch `Option Strict On` and fix any error that shows.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this please, I don't know anything about this option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code works for me (**EDITED to include some error checking**):

```
Public Class ExcelProcess
    Private xlApp As Excel.Application
    Private xlBook As Excel.Workbook
    Private xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet

    Public Sub New(ByVal file As String)
        xlApp = New Excel.Application
        'xlApp.Visible = True 'for debugging
        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False 'prevent user dialogs
        xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(file)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Quit()
        If Not IsNothing(xlBook) Then
            xlBook.Save()
            xlBook.Close()
        End If
        If Not IsNothing(xlApp) Then xlApp.Quit()
    End Sub

    Public Sub deleteSheet(ByVal Index As Integer)
        If Index > xlBook.Worksheets.Count Then
            Throw New Exception("You cannot delete a worksheet that does not exist")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If xlBook.Worksheets.Count = 1 Then
            Throw New Exception("You cannnot delete the only worksheet in a workbook")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        xlSheet = CType(xlBook.Worksheets(Index), Excel.Worksheet)
        xlSheet.Activate()
        xlSheet.Delete()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I don't know what magic happened... seriously.. this is really STRANGE..
I just changed to xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(file) and not to have a seperate Books variable.. 
And I just did nothing else.. and it worked.. like magic !

Its Strange but I am so happy !!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you need to save your workbook after you do the delete (using `SaveAs`). Otherwise it will just delete the in-memory worksheet and when your Excel object goes out of scope it will just close the workbook without saving the changes.

```
Books.SaveAs(...)
```

Comment: I used..
    WB.Save()
    WB.Close()

But that didn't helped.. its still not working..
Actually I was having this in my original code but I forgot to write it here !